# Get 1 if number of rows in one table is equal to number of rows in other table

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables

```
table a->
Class_ID  |  name  | class
1         |  abc   | a
1         |  def   | a
2         |  ghi   | b
2         |  jkl   | b
2         |  mno   | b
3         |  pqr   | c
3         |  stu   | c

table b->
Class_ID  |  class
1         |  a
1         |  a
2         |  b
2         |  b
3         |  c
3         |  c
```

I want the result to return 1 for CLASS_ID = 1 & 3 and 0 for CLASS_ID = 2, i.e. query should return 1 if number of rows in table a is equal to no of rows in table b.

Comment: could you please tabulate your result,so its easy to interprete?

Comment: i want query to result 1 when i run it for CLASS_ID = 1, dont want the tabular result of the entire table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Class_ID, acount = bcount as count_matches
from (select Class_ID, COUNT(*) acount
      from TableA
      group by Class_ID) a
JOIN (select Class_ID, COUNT(*) acount
      from TableB
      group by Class_ID) b
USING (Class_ID)
```

Note that this query assumes that there are no missing class IDs in the tables. If just one of them can be missing some class_IDs, you can use a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, depending on which it could be (and use `IFNULL(Xcount, 0)` for the count from that table). If either of them can be missing some, you need a FULL JOIN, but MySQL doesn't support it. If you search SO you can find the workaround solutions.

If you just want to do it for one class ID at a time, it's even simpler:

```
select (select count(*) from TableA where Class_ID = 1) =
       (select count(*) from TableB where Class_Id = 1) as count_matches
```

Comment: thanks for ur response, but i dont want result for entire table, but for a specific Class_ID

Comment: Then put a WHERE clause in the subqueries.

Comment: Added a simpler query for a specific Class_ID

Comment: works as a charm, but can we optimize it a bit, cuz actual table is very complex and this is a subquery for a main query

Comment: I think that's as optimal as it can get. Just make sure you have indexes on Class_ID.

Comment: thanks for the query, adding index on CLass_ID is not an viable option for me in this case, cuz the table is already associated with couple of index. Thanks again

Comment: If you can't index the column, there's no way to optimize the query. It has to scan all the rows to get the row count, there's no way around it.